# Have Changes Reflected for Everyone on HTML webpage

Tags: javascript, html

not exactly sure how to ask this question as I am new to web development, but I am currently working on a webpage game.  I have some javascript that reveals an underlying image behind a card background when the card is clicked on but there are certain occasions when I want everyone to see these changes (the card reveal) and others when I want only the user who clicked the card to see the reveal.  Is there any way that I can do this using HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Currently, changes to the DOM on one person's HTML file are only seen on their own computer, not everyone who is on that HTML file playing the game.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Webpages are always local to the computer showing them.

If you want changes made on one computer to also be reflected in another one, you will have to use a server to pass the changes through it.